# Select design pattern - user stage

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm struggling to point a finger into the right design pattern.

I have a web site which user can register and interact with the system.
I want to add the following abilities to a user:

1. Each user will be in a stage. Let's say that we have 5 stages.
   when user is register, he will be in the 1-st stage.
2. User will be able to climb to the next stage.
   To do so, he will need to complete X tasks.
   (There will be 20 tasks in the system).
3. In each stage, the user will be able to buy benefits with the points that he gain in each task that he completed.

What's the appropriate design pattern to use here?

Thanks.